# Adding CSS to a C# Web Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications

What is the best way to add a cascading stylesheet (CSS) to a web application project in visual studio 2010?

For example if I have the followingL

```
<asp:Label ID ="lName_lbl" runat="server" text="Last Name:  "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="lName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
```

How do i style all asp labels to have the same properties?

Comment: Let's watch our tag choices a little better, m'kay? `visual` isn't exactly a very good tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers have correctly mentioned, you can use the CssClass attribute for controls that support it.

You can also style the elements using [**CSS Selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

ASP.Net makes it easy to add stylesheets to your application via the [**App_Themes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) folder. CSS specified in here corresponding to the theme you set in the page or web.config will be automatically loaded. No need to link the css manually.

EDIT:

If you don't already have an App_Themes folder, right click your project, and choose Add->Add ASP.Net Folder->Theme and this will create it for you. To make sure the Theme is used set it in the web.config (via the <pages theme="" attribute) or at the page level. See the [**App_Themes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx) page for more information.

Comment: creating a blank web application does not add an App_Themes folder

Comment: You can right click on the web application at the project level, select "Add ASP_Net folder" (or similar), and one of the options will be App_Themes

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET controls have the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property which you can use to style your control. There's also some good advice on using CSS with ASP.NET [here](http://nimad.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/10-rules-for-effective-use-of-css-in-aspnet/).

Comment: Ok but how do I include the css into my document? Using the standard <link> tag available in HTML? Is there a better way to do it within vis studio 2010?

Comment: Yes, the output is still HTML, so you can use the standard `<link>` or `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CssClass attribute on your labels or you could define a style to apply to all spans since .NET renders `<asp:Label />` as a span.