# ASP.NET page is not loading CSS styles

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

This is a simple website in ASP.NET with C# using VS 2010. I have following directory structure for this project:

[image]

The starting page is `Default.aspx` and it loads perfectly. But when I open page `Interface/SystemAdminLogin.aspx` from Default page, it loads with no CSS styles. I have imported CSS style sheet in Master Page. Here is how I am referencing MasterPage file in both .aspx files:

`Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

`SystemAdminLogin.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SystemAdminLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

I dont see any mistake with my code but why Page in Interface folder is not loading CSS styles??
Please help.

Here is the master page code where i am importing css file:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Facial Recognition Bank System</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And here is the part of CSS file code:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff url(../images/img01.jpg) repeat-x left top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Paste the part of the Master Page file where the css is linked

Comment: You might find it easier to use ASP.Net themes - this will take care of all of this for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8564035/1073107 or the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx

Comment: @AshwinSingh no, not using IIS.

Comment: @Azeem try to load the page without use cache data, press CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The stylesheets included in your master page are using relative paths.

Specify your stylesheet links with `runat=server` and prefix them with the virtual web root path (`~`):

```
<link href="~/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />
```

OR:

```
<link href="/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" runat="server" />
```

But keep in mind that the first option is recommended. The second will not work when you publish your site in a **virtual directory**.

After last comment...

The image URL's in CSSs should be updated as well, in order to not use relative paths or do any **path traversal** (../).

> background: #fff url(images/img01.jpg) repeat-x left top;

For this option you will need to move the images folder inside the Styles folder (it's a good practice to do so).

**Final update:**

Looks like that the `head` element also needs to be `runat=server` in order for ASP.NET relative paths (~) to work within `link` elements with `runat=server`.

Comment: Hi, when i used first option then Default.aspx is not loading CSS styles too... I have added part of CSS code in post. Please look into it. thanks

Comment: If it still doesn't work then update your post with how the markup looks now and also describe what happens.

Comment: I have updated code as you said and also placed images folder in Styles but same issue!!! Default.aspx loads css fine but SystemAdminLogin.aspx is not... I am attaching project files in my post, it will make you better understanding of what i have done and what needs to be done...

Comment: Please download it from [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?2m4y33rygq0a7o6). thanks for your help

Comment: OK, fixed. I'll update my answer. You can download it from here: http://sdrv.ms/KTy1xN

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in my master pages:

```
<asp:content ID="xContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="headContent" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>Folder/Folder/Filename.css" />
</asp:Content>'
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've spent hours trying to get a custom CSS file to work on my DNN module, and this is the only thing I've found that works short of including the CSS in <style> tags!

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat="server"` to the head attribute and also ensure the link targets the root as in ("~/path to css")

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title>Page Title Here</title>
    <link href="~/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with (~ in your path):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Facial Recognition Bank System</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="~/Styles/style.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Comment: That won't work. The `link` element has to be with `runat=server` in order for ASP.NET virtual paths to work.

Comment: yes @the coon is right. The ~ is NOT working with or without runat server attribute...

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development for debug. And in the _Layout.cshtml I had the asp-append-version missing.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - SALUS UAV</title>

<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

I fixed that and it was all good again:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - SALUS UAV</title>

<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```