# master page does not load css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, master-pages

so i referenced css file in master page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/default.css" runat="server" />
```

and it actually shows in visual studio in design view, but for some reason does not show in web browser. why is that? btw the css file and masterpage and the image folder are all in the root directory.
css file:

```css
*
{
padding: 0em;
margin: 0em;
}

body
{
background:url('images/bg1.jpg');
padding: 30px 0px 35px 0px;
}

body,input
{
font-size: 10pt;
font-family: "georgia", "times new roman", serif;
color: #333333;
}

p
{
line-height: 1.5em;
margin-bottom: 1.0em;
text-align: justify;
}

a
{
color: #B96D00;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
}


h3 span
{
font-weight: normal;
}

h3,h4
{
display: inline;
font-weight: bold;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
}

h3
{
font-size: 1.7em;
padding-right: 34px;
background-image: url('images/db1.gif');
}

h4
{
font-size: 1.2em;
padding-right: 28px;
background-image: url('images/db2.gif');
}

.contentarea
{
padding-top: 1.3em;
}

img
{
border: solid 1px #6F5230;
}

img.left
{
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0em 1.8em 1.4em 0em;
}

img.right
{
position: relative;
float: right;
margin: 0em 0em 1.8em 1.8em;
}

.divider1
{
position: relative;
background: #fff url('images/border2.gif') repeat-x;
height: 14px;
margin: 2.0em 0em 1.5em 0em;
clear: both;
}

.divider2
{
position: relative;
height: 1px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #eaeaea;
margin: 2.0em 0em 2.0em 0em;
}

.post .details
{
position: relative;
top: -1.5em;
font-size: 0.8em;
color: #787878;
}

.post ul.controls
{
clear: both;
}

.post ul.controls li
{
display: inline;
font-size: 0.8em;
}

.post ul.controls li a
{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
padding: 0em 1.0em 0em 20px;
}

.post ul.controls li a.printerfriendly
{
background-image: url('images/icon-printerfriendly.gif');
}

.post ul.controls li a.comments
{
background-image: url('images/icon-comments.gif');
}

.post ul.controls li a.more
{
background-image: url('images/icon-more.gif');
}

.box
{
position: relative;
background: #FDFCF6 url('images/boxbg.gif') repeat-x;
left: -1.5em;
top: -1.5em;
padding: 1.5em;
border-bottom: solid 1px #E1D2BD;
margin-bottom: 1.0em;
}

ul.linklist
{
list-style: none;
}

ul.linklist li
{
line-height: 2.0em;
}

#upbg
{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 275px;
background: #fff url('images/bg2.jpg') repeat-x;
z-index: 1;
}

#outer
{
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
width: 82%;
border: solid 7px #fff;
background-color: #fff;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 8.0em;
background: #2B2B2B url('images/topbg.gif') repeat-x;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#headercontent
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0em;
padding: 0em 2.0em 1.3em 2.0em;
}

#headercontent h1
{
font-weight: normal;
color: #fff;
font-size: 2.5em;
}

#headercontent h1 sup
{
color: #777;
}

#headercontent h2
{
font-size: 1.0em;
font-weight: normal;
color: #aaa;
}

#search
{
position: absolute;
top: 5.5em;
right: 2.0em;
padding-right: 0.0em;
}

#search input.text
{
margin-right: 0.5em;
vertical-align: middle;
border-top: solid 1px #000000;
border-right: 0px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #777777;
border-left: 0px;
padding: 0.15em;
width: 10.0em;
}

#search input.submit
{
background: #939B00 url('images/buttonbg.gif') repeat-x;
border: solid 1px #5F6800;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0.25em;
font-size: 0.8em;
color: #F2F3DE;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#headerpic
{
position: relative;
height: 200px;
background: #fff url('images/hdrpic.jpg') no-repeat top left;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#menu
{
position: relative;
background: #7F8400 url('images/menubg.gif') repeat-x top left;
height: 3.5em;
padding: 0em 1.0em 0em 1.0em;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#menu ul
{
position: absolute;
top: 1.1em;
}

#menu ul li
{
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a
{
padding: 0.5em 1.0em 0.9em 1.0em;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu ul li a.active
{
background: #7F8400 url('images/menuactive.gif') repeat-x top left;
}

#menubottom
{
background: #fff url('images/border1.gif') repeat-x;
height: 14px;
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

#content
{
padding: 0em 2.0em 0em 2.0em;
}

#primarycontainer
{
float: left;
margin-right: -18.0em;
width: 100%;
}

#primarycontent
{
margin: 1.5em 22.0em 0em 0em;
}

#secondarycontent
{
margin-top: 1.5em;
float: right;
width: 18.0em;
}

#footer
{
position: relative;
height: 2.0em;
clear: both;
padding-top: 5.0em;
background: #fff url('images/border2.gif') repeat-x 0em 2.5em;
font-size: 0.8em;
}

#footer .left
{
position: absolute;
left: 2.0em;
bottom: 1.2em;
}

#footer .right
{
position: absolute;
right: 2.0em;
bottom: 1.2em;
}
```

master page:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Project3.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Zahra Moradi</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/default.css" runat="server"  />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="upbg">
    </div>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headercontent">
                <h1>
                    E-Library</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="">
        <div id="search">
            <input type="text" class="text" maxlength="64" name="keywords" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        </form>
        <div id="headerpic">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <!-- HINT: Set the class of any menu link below to "active" to make it appear active -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Library.aspx">Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="menubottom">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="left">
                &copy; 2015 Zahra Moradi. All rights reserved.</div>
            <div class="right">
                Design by <a href="http://www.nodethirtythree.com/">NodeThirtyThree Design</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already tried other solutions posted on similar questions but didn't work for me. like adding runat="server" and so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET page is not loading CSS styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168668/asp-net-page-is-not-loading-css-styles)

Comment: @Tyr i actually tried the solutions for that question but didn't work for me

Comment: Look at your network tab, does it give you a 404 error for the CSS file?

Comment: Try to call the css file directly like `http://host/pathtocss/file.css` to look if it's present or use the network tab of your browser to look if it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Same suggestion as @Tyr. Try loading the CSS file as a web link instead of a local file. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/website/css/default.css"/>
```

That should work. If it doesn't, use the developer tools on your browser (Google Chrome is the best). In Chrome, right click anywhere on the page and click 'Inspect Element'. Are there any errors coming up to do with your CSS file being displayed on the bar on the right? If there is, what are they?

Comment: but i'm not using any web host. i'm using visual studio. how do i use a web link.

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad09f4da%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) may help.

Comment: i found where i went wrong. in web.config i denied access to unauthorized users and because css file was in the same directory as home.aspx it didn't load so i added `<location path="default.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>` to web.config file. now i have another problem the images do not load

Comment: Do the same thing for your images as you did with the CSS file?