# ASP.NET page CSS styles load in Visual Studio but not on browser

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

For this ASP.net web form project, I created a `Default.css` for the `Default.aspx` so I can write the style separately. I was able to change the width of the search bar in the split screen, and it show me exactly what I want, but when I load this on Chrome does not do anything. but if I copy the textbox code from `default.aspx` to `Site.master` it will change the style in both split screen and on Chrome. Can someone tell me why is doing anything with the first method?

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.vb" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">    
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="~/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
```

```
<div id="body">
    <%-- Link up with the asp:content in Default.aspx --%>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <%-- Default Main Body Content --%>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
    </section>
</div>
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>Report Titial is showing hererererere</h1>
        </hgroup>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Search" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true">Search...</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Btn_Search" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
</section>
```

Default.css

```
#TB_Search
{
    width: 515px;
}
```

I was reviewing this post but is not helping me at all:
[ASP.NET page is not loading CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168668/asp-net-page-is-not-loading-css-styles)

Comment: I think that answer should help. You have to use the server path `~` for your css file. The path should then be from the root of the project. `href="~/content/default.css"`. If this doesn't help, please add your current directory structure for the css file's location, with regard to the project root.

Comment: @ps2goat I did add the ~/. And I don't know why but sometimes when I refresh it will work and if I refresh it few more times it doesn't work. Is this a bug?

Comment: You should use the `BundleConfig` and use `<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") %>` too

Comment: I usually disable caching with the browser's dev tools when developing locally. That can help. @David's idea is good, but not required for your immediate problem. I remember having to use that with IE8 because it couldn't handle more than 31 linked resources, if i recall. lol.